# How to let users create email address of my domain?

Tags: wordpress, email

I bought a domain of the name of my valley which is myvalley.pk (not writing the whole address because I don't want it to be shown in google search). The hosting package includes unlimited email addresses and unlimited bandwidth and unlimited storage space.

As it is one of a kind domain so is it a good idea to let the users (people from my valley) have their email accounts of my domain? For example "MyName@myvalley.pk".

If it is not bad to do that, how can I let the users create the email address of their choice? Right now I use cpanel to create an email address of that domain. I am using wordpress on that website.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple as it may seem.

As you are using a hosting from some company, they may and may not let you automate email creation.

Check with your hosting provider how to best approach this.